# Show/remove classes while scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just need to show div while scrolling down and remove another div at same time. 
I try with this code and this is working as I expected. The problem is, If I scroll to top I need to show the removed class and hide current class. (opposite side of this)

This is my code.

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
     if (scroll >= 0) {   
     $(".left-nav").removeClass("white-nav");  
    }
  });
```

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `addClass()` to add class when `scrollTop` is 0, since you are already check for `scroll >= 0`, you just need to add an `else` like this:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
     if (scroll > 0) {   
        $(".left-nav").removeClass("white-nav");  
     } else {
        $(".left-nav").addClass("white-nav");
     }
 });
```

Comment: This his peace of cord is not working. I don't know why. Technically it seems correct.

Comment: @CssSY the condition in `if` was wrong, it should addClass if `scroll === 0`, I have changed the code it now it works.

Comment: I have a same situation in logo. I cannot use addClass or removeClass because logo isn't a background image. Can you help me the way to do if I post it in a new post?

Comment: @CssSY yeah sure, I'll try!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925334/hide-div-while-scrolling-down

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
  $(".left-nav").toggleClass("white-nav", scroll <= 0);
});
```

But be aware, that complex code in scroll event handlers can lead to a laggy performance while scrolling the page. Especially DOM manipulation during scrolling can lead to severe performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can used toggleClass() to do this 
    http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
 var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
 if (scroll >0) {   
 $(".left-nav").toggleClass("white-nav");  
}
else{
$(".left-nav").toggleClass("white-nav");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {     
   $(".left-nav").toggleClass("white-nav", $(window).scrollTop() <= 0); 
});
```

```css
.white-nav{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='left-nav white-nav'>Hey</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>nothing here</div>
```