# Hide div while scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to hide an image when scroll down and show another image. When scroll to top of the page, first image needs to show and other image needs to be hide.

I tried with this code.

```
//This is the image I just want to show at first
<img src="images/logo-wh.png" alt="" class="logo-white"> 

//This is the image I just want to show when scroll down
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="logo-default">

.logo-default{
  display:none;
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('.logo-white').hide();
    } else {
        $('.logo-default').show();
    }
 });
```

But it isn't working as I expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: whats the exact issue you're facing. How does it not work as expected?

Comment: Could you explain what happened that made you write "isn't working as expected" please ? It would help.

Comment: I suggest that do not directly change style.display property of an element. just add a class to body that gives you the state of scroll like 'scrolled' or something and use that class as container in css selector like '.scrolled .logo' new angular frameworks do things similar to this example but they are using attributes to change scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify a bit the show and hide inside the `if...else` statement:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.logo-white').hide();
    $('.logo-default').show();
  } else {
    $('.logo-white').show();
    $('.logo-default').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.logo-default {
  display: none;
}
#wrapper{
  height: 1000px;
  background: #adadad;
}

img{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
    <img src="http://www.alessandrobianchetti.com/uploads/1/8/5/3/18531856/1842659_orig.jpg" alt="" class="logo-white"> 
    <img src="http://www.pietrarosa.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/paesaggi-1.jpg" alt="" class="logo-default">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like so:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
        $('.logo-default').hide();
        $('.logo-white').show();
    } else {
        $('.logo-default').show();
        $('.logo-white').hide();
    }
 });
```

```css
.logo-white,
.logo-default {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

.logo-default{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" alt="" class="logo-white"> 

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/" alt="" class="logo-default">

<div style="height: 2000px;width: 10px;background-color: orange;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's working example,
just used both elements with hide show differences you needed.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('.logo-white').hide();
        $('.logo-default').show();
    } else {
        $('.logo-default').hide();
        $('.logo-white').show();
    }
 });
$(window).trigger('scroll');
```

```css
.logo-white, .logo-default {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.logo-default { background: #d20000; }

body { height: 500px; overflow: scroll; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo-white"></div>

<div class="logo-default"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code :

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('.logo-white').hide();
         $('.logo-default').show();
    } else {
        $('.logo-default').hide();
        $('.logo-white').show();
    }
 });
```

```css
.logo-default {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/07/22/31/golden-eagle-627943_960_720.jpg" alt="" class="logo-white">

<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/08/12/17/13/white-tailed-eagle-416795_960_720.jpg" alt="" class="logo-default">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("window ").scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop()>0){
$(".logo-white").attr("src","images/logo-wh.png");
}
else{
$(".logo-white").attr("src","images/logo.png");
}
});
```

Delete the second img tag

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
height: x;
overflow: hidden;
```